# Setting a value to a function in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

I am trying to do a reverse String problem in C and I am aware that there are other ways to do this but I am confused as to why the following solution is not working. (I'll put the output below)

```
/*Write a function reverse (s) that reverses the character strings. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

int ngetline(char s[], int lim);
void nreverse(char s[], int index);

main(){
    int len;
    char line[MAXLENGTH];

    while(len = ngetline(line, MAXLENGTH) > 0)
    {
        printf("length: %d\n", len);
        nreverse(line, len);
    }

    printf("%s", line);

    return 0;

}


int ngetline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <  lim -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    return i;
}


void nreverse(char s[], int len)
{
    int i, backIndex;
    int halfway;
    char temp;
    backIndex = len - 2;
    halfway = backIndex / 2;



    for(i = 0; i <= halfway; ++i)
    {
        printf("In the for\n");
        temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[backIndex];
        s[backIndex] = temp;
        --backIndex;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
./reverseString
entering while
String to be Reversed
i: 22
length: 1
```

As you can see in the code, I set the length equal to the function ngetline() which returns i.  But then when I print/try to get length, it returns 1.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's a `c` [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) thing.  Since relation (`>`) has higher precedence than assignment (`=`), it is evaluated first, so you are assigning the value `True` (or `1`) to the variable `len`.  Try putting the assignment in parentheses:

```
while((len = ngetline(line, MAXLENGTH)) > 0)
```